# Symfony/Twig how to render a Route set by anotation?

Tags: php, symfony, routes, twig, url-routing

Let's say I have this code in a controller:

```
<?php

namespace Foo\BarBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration as Mvc;

/**
 * @Mvc\Route("/foo/bar")
 */
class TestController extends Controller
    /**
     * @Mvc\Route("/test/{id}", requirements={"id" = "[0-9]{1,6}"})
     * @Mvc\Template
     *
     * @return view
     */
    public function testAction($id)
    {
        return array('test' => $id);
    }
}
```

How can I link to this route in a twig template? Usually I can just call

```
{{ path('route_name', {'paramkey': 'paramvalue'}) }}
```

But here I have no name to call. Same thing, how would I call it in a controller (for a redirect)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you omit the name it's being autogenerated for you.

The autogenerated name is a lowercase concatenation of bundle + controller + action. For example, if you have:

- Bundle `AppBundle`
- Controller `MyController`
- Action: `testAction()`

the name would be `app_my_test`.

You can list all routes using `Terminal`:

```
php app/console router:debug
```

All routes' names, including those autogenerated, will be there.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Yeah, just add `name="your_route_name"` to your route declaration.